# pg_dump in Docker container

Tags: bash, shell, docker, command-line, kubernetes

I am trying to run `pg_dump` in a Docker container via `kubectl` and save the output to my local machine.

Here's what I have so far:

`kubectl exec -it MY_POD_NAME -- pg_dump -h DB_HOST -U USER_NAME SCHEMA_NAME > backup.sql`

However this just hangs currently. I am fairly certain it's due to the `--` ignoring the `>`

`kubectl exec -it MY_POD_NAME -- pg_dump -h DB_HOST -U USER_NAME SCHEMA_NAME` outputs to the console as expected.

Comment: Let me recommend you mount data in a volume located in host to keep data if container terminates because its entrypoint ends.
So, your data would be persistent.

Comment: I don't want it to be persisted to the container, I want it to be persisted to my local machine hence why I'm redirecting it with `>`

Comment: What I say is a way to be persistent in local machine, not container.
If you are using Linux, you can `docker run` postgre container with `-v /tmp/yourdatabackup:/var/lib/postgresql/8.x/`
Hence, your data in container will be always accessible from host and therefore persistent outside container

Comment: @Alex Galera is right. The data persistency on docker containers is recommended to do mounting volumes on host machine.

Comment: The Docker containers are hosted in Kubernetes in AWS. I appreciate the help but your suggestion doesn't apply in this scenario and doesn't address my actual problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Managed to solve myself - not the most elegant solution but it works.

First I open a shell on a pod in the cluster which has network access to the RDS instance:

`kubectl exec -it psql-xxx-xxx sh`

Once connected to the shell, run `pg_dump` to backup the database:

`pg_dump -h db.internal.dns -U user schema_name > backup.sql`

Once the backup completes, exit the container and copy the file from the pod to my local:

`kubectl cp psql-xxx-xxx:/backup.sql ./backup.sql`

Will continue searching for a streamlined way to do this.

Answer (score 6):

Use `kubectl port-forward POD_NAME 6000:5342` to forward your pod port (assumed to be exposed on `5432`) onto `localhost:6000`.

And then run `pg_dump` directly with hostname as `localhost` and port as `6000`

`$ pg_dump -h DB_HOST -U USER_NAME SCHEMA_NAME > backup.sql`

Comment: Unfortunately this would only solve my problem if postgres were running on localhost of the Docker container I `port-forward` to. In my case, this is a remote postgres instance.

Comment: No, this will work with remote also. Are you not able to?

Comment: How does it know where the remote host is? If my docker container connects to the remote instance via something like `database.internaldns` then when I connect via `localhost` on my local machine, where is `database.internaldns` specified?

Comment: kubectl connects to the remote pod.

Answer (score 2):

If the database is indeed running as a docker image in remote kubernetes instance, I was successful with

`kubectl exec -it POD_NAME -- pg_dump -h localhost -U DB_USER DB_NAME > backup.sql`

Where localhost points to localhost in remote instance. Running directly from local terminal, this saves database dump to my local machine, no matter the database itself is running in the cloud.